# How to add 'HttpLibrary' from RobotFramework to Red.xml on Eclipse

Tags: python-3.x, eclipse-plugin, robotframework, eclipse-oxygen

I trying to write test scripts using HttpLibrary (from robot framework) on Eclipse RED editor and below are the steps i have performed -

**Steps performed**

1. Installed robot framework HttpLibrary using below command

> pip install --upgrade robotframework-httplibrary

2. From Settings-> Imports, added HttpLibrary to my script

> *** Settings ***
>       Library    HttpLibrary

3. **'Unknown 'HttpLibrary' library. Try to use Quick Fix (Ctrl+1) or add library to red.xml for proper validation'** error message is noticed on hovering the HttpLibrary line in my script.
4. However upon looking at Red.xml ->Referenced libraries tab, HttpLibrary is listed in the libraries block [HttpLibrary in Red.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8HQo.png)

I am wondering if there is any different procedure to add libraries to Red.xml. I am stuck on trying different ways to add HttpLibrary to my script.

Answer (score 2):

After few hours of investigation, i have found root cause of the issue.
I am using Python 3.6.4 in my machine and installed Robot Framework on it.
HttpLibrary supports only Python 2 and so though the library is listed in the Red.xml referenced libraries tab, still my Robot Framework script was not able to reference and run it properly.
Please note that not all the Robot Framework libraries are supported by Python 3.6.4

Answer (score 0):

This occasionally happens. Even when the library is already present in the project config file (RED.xml) and present in the project tree panel. Using CTR+1 and opting for the quick fix option will generally correct this issue without any visual difference.

In the [HttpLibrary Github documentation](https://github.com/peritus/robotframework-httplibrary#usage) there the usage section also highlights that the library should be imported like:

```
*** Settings*** 
Library    HttpLibrary.HTTP
```

This gives a different result.

Comment: CTRL+1 option is not fixing this issue. Thanks

Comment: Have you saved both RED.xml and the robot file afterwards?

Comment: Yes i have saved RED.xml and robot file also...still the issue is same.

Comment: Updated the answer with an Library Import example. Perhaps this is the real culprit.

Comment: Sorry, i have tried 'Library    HttpLibrary.HTTP' setting earlier. Still it dint work.